What is the total mass sent to orbit by SpaceX?
SpaceX currently has 363 or 364 (depending on how you count Amos-6) launches and counting. How much mass worth of payload have the sent up as of right now (August 14, 2024)?

Related: what is the total mass sent into orbit over all history

You could also probably answer this by adding up the contents of the BryceTech reports from here https://brycetech.com/reports since they break it down by provider.

As of August 2024, SpaceX have cumulatively put approximately 4000 Tons into orbit.
Here are some visualizations:


This data was obtained by scraping the wikipedia pages for launch. Specifically this one, this one, and this one. The code used for this is below:
import pandas as pd
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateutil import parser

urls = [
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches_(2010%E2%80%932019)",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches_(2020%E2%80%932022)",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches"
]

# Data issues:

# - In later launches, crew dragon mass often not included. 


# Assume Dragon mass in kg 
dragon1_mass_kg = 4200 
dragon2_mass_kg = 12500 
default_mass = 5000
classified_mass = 3700

import pandas as pd

# Define the correct headers based on the image
correct_headers = [
    "Flight No.",
    "Date and time (UTC)",
    "Version, Booster",
    "Launch site",
    "Payload",
    "Payload mass",
    "Orbit",
    "Customer",
    "Launch outcome",
    "Booster landing"
]

all_tables = []
seen_flight_numbers = set()  # To track seen flight numbers

for url in urls:
    try:
        # Read all tables from the page
        tables = pd.read_html(url, header=0)

        for table in tables:
            # Rename the columns to match the correct headers
            table.columns = correct_headers
            
            # Filter out rows where the headers are repeated
            table = table[table["Flight No."] != "Flight No."]

            # Drop rows with duplicated flight numbers, keeping only the first
            table = table[~table["Flight No."].duplicated()]

            # Filter out repeated flight numbers after the first instance
            table = table[~table["Flight No."].isin(seen_flight_numbers)]
            seen_flight_numbers.update(table["Flight No."].tolist())

            # Apply filters based on "Orbit" and "Launch outcome" columns
            table = table[~table["Orbit"].str.contains("sub-orbital", case=False, na=False)]
            table = table[~table["Launch outcome"].str.contains("failure|precluded", case=False, na=False)]


            # Remove Wikipedia reference notations like [21] from all string columns
            for col in table.columns:
                if table[col].dtype == object:
                    table[col] = table[col].str.replace(r'\[\d+\]', '', regex=True).str.strip()


            # Create the "sanitized payload mass" and "sanitized upmass" columns
            sanitized_payload_mass = []
            sanitized_upmass = []
            estimated = []

            # Initialize the lists
            sanitized_payload_mass = []
            sanitized_upmass = []
            estimated = []

            for payload in table["Payload mass"]:
                # Initialize default values
                mass_value = None
                upmass_value = None
                estimated_value = True

                # Extract the kg value using regex
                match = re.search(r'(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)\s*kg', payload)
                if match:
                    # Convert extracted kg value to an integer
                    kg_value = int(match.group(1).replace(',', ''))
                    mass_value = kg_value
                    estimated_value = False  # Exact value found
                    # Check if the string contains "(excl. Dragon mass)" and add dragon mass if true
                    if "(excl. Dragon mass)" in payload:
                        upmass_value = kg_value + dragon1_mass_kg
                    else:
                        upmass_value = kg_value
                else:
                    # If no kg value is found, determine based on other information
                    if "(excl. Dragon Mass)" in payload:
                        mass_value = 0
                        upmass_value = dragon1_mass_kg
                        estimated_value = False  # Exact value inferred
                    elif "classified" in payload.lower():
                        mass_value = classified_mass
                        upmass_value = classified_mass
                    else:
                        mass_value = default_mass
                        upmass_value = default_mass

                # Append the calculated or default values
                sanitized_payload_mass.append(mass_value)
                sanitized_upmass.append(upmass_value)
                estimated.append(estimated_value)

            # Add the new columns to the table
            table["sanitized payload mass"] = sanitized_payload_mass
            table["sanitized upmass"] = sanitized_upmass
            table["estimated"] = estimated

            # After creating the sanitized columns and before saving the DataFrame:
            table["sanitized payload mass"] = table["sanitized payload mass"].astype('Int64')
            table["sanitized upmass"] = table["sanitized upmass"].astype('Int64')


            all_tables.append(table)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to scrape {url}: {e}")

# Concatenate all tables into a single DataFrame
if all_tables:
    combined_df = pd.concat(all_tables, ignore_index=True)
    print(combined_df.head())

    # Save to a TSV file (tab-separated values)
    combined_df.to_csv("falcon_9_and_heavy_launches.csv", sep='\t', index=False)



    # Extract the year directly from the 'Date and time (UTC)' column
    combined_df['Year'] = combined_df['Date and time (UTC)'].str.extract(r'(20\d{2})')

    # Group by year and sum the 'sanitized payload mass' and 'sanitized upmass'
    yearly_summary = combined_df.groupby('Year').agg({
        'sanitized payload mass': 'sum',
        'sanitized upmass': 'sum'
    }).reset_index()

    # Display the new table
    print(yearly_summary)

    # Convert kilograms to tons
    yearly_summary['sanitized payload mass'] = yearly_summary['sanitized payload mass'] / 1000  # Convert to tons
    yearly_summary['sanitized upmass'] = yearly_summary['sanitized upmass'] / 1000  # Convert to tons

    # Calculate the additional mass (upmass - payload mass)
    yearly_summary['additional mass'] = yearly_summary['sanitized upmass'] - yearly_summary['sanitized payload mass']

    # Create a stacked bar chart
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.bar(yearly_summary['Year'], yearly_summary['sanitized payload mass'], label='Payload Mass', color='darkblue')
    plt.bar(yearly_summary['Year'], yearly_summary['additional mass'], bottom=yearly_summary['sanitized payload mass'], label='Dragon 1 Capsule Mass', color='teal')

    # Add labels and title
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Mass to orbit (Tons)')
    plt.title('Yearly SpaceX Total Launch Mass')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.legend()

    # Add gridlines and remove top and right borders
    plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)

    # Show the plot
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    
    

    # Assuming combined_df is your DataFrame
    # Use dateutil.parser to parse dates, which is more flexible with formats
    combined_df['Date and time (UTC)'] = combined_df['Date and time (UTC)'].apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x, fuzzy=True))

    # Sort the DataFrame by the datetime column to ensure proper chronological order
    combined_df = combined_df.sort_values(by='Date and time (UTC)')

    # Convert kilograms to tons for the 'sanitized upmass' column
    combined_df['sanitized upmass'] = combined_df['sanitized upmass'] / 1000  # Convert to tons

    # Calculate the cumulative sum of sanitized upmass
    combined_df['cumulative sanitized upmass'] = combined_df['sanitized upmass'].cumsum()

    # Create a line plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(combined_df['Date and time (UTC)'], combined_df['cumulative sanitized upmass'], color='darkblue', marker='o')

    # Add labels and title
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Upmass (Tons)')
    plt.title('SpaceX Mass to Orbit Over Time')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    # Add gridlines and remove top and right borders
    plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)

    # Show the plot
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

else:
    print("No tables found.")


Caveats
There are some issues with this analysis:

Payload masses for classified payloads and rideshare are not disclosed by SpaceX, so estimates fill in. Averaging non-classified military missions led to a ballpark of 3700 kg, and rideshare missions were estimated at 5000 kg.
Wikipedia data is somewhat mixed on how Dragon or generally spacecraft mass is added to the up-mass. Some CRS missions may only be indicated with payload values.

